# IF Manage Stock is No, then show always show "in stock"

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this code for the Stock status on the product page, so that if stock is less that 1 is shows as out of stock.

```
 <?php if ($_product->getStockItem()->getQty() < 1): ?>
            <span class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to add to it so that if stock is < 1 and Manage Stock is yes then, show "out of stock",

So basicly if Manage is no, its always showing in stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if ($_product->getStockItem()->getQty() < 1 && $_product->getStockItem()->getManageStock()): ?>
    <span class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will better idea to use `isSaleable()` as out of stock checker of product

```
<?php if (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <span class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain "isSaleable" to me? as our current setup we want users to be able to buy goods that are out of stock ( hence the original edit)

Comment: You can enable Backorders to allow buying products that are out of stock. Go to System > Config > Catalog tab > Inventory > Product Stock Settings > Backorders and allow backorders. No custom code required

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort  that only works if there was 5 in stock and customer order 10.  But if stock is 0 then it says "out of stock" and you can't order